# Having trouble with a while loop that gets a certain series of numbers from an input

Tags: java, if-statement, random, input, while-loop

I'm trying to half the input if it % 12 == 0, but if it isn't then you multiply it by 3 and add 1 onto the sum.

The question that I'm working off is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOxQs.png

[image]

With the code I have currently(which is below), if I enter 12, like in the question I start off with 6, but then the results begin to go wrong and then they go insanely wrong with values in the millions and negative millions etc.

```
import java.util.*;
public class sheet12t3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        hailstone(aNumber);
    }

    public static void hailstone(int x)
    {
        int count = 1;
        int max = 0;
        String results = "Hailstone series for the number " + x + " is ";
        while (x >= 1)
        {
            if (x % 12 == 0)
                x = x / 2;
            else
                x = 3 * x + 1;

            count++;

            results += + x + ", ";

            if (x > max)
                max = x;
        }
        results += "a total of " + count + " numbers in this sequence with a maximum value of " + max;
        System.out.print(results);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says divide by two if the number is even. But you divide by 2 only when it is dividable by 12.

Change this line

```
(x % 12 == 0)
```

to

```
(x % 2 == 0)
```

And change  `while (x >= 1)` to  `while (x > 1)`

Comment: Can't believe i misread that, Thanks! Although when I changed it, when I execute the code and enter 12, the program freezes, I get no output, the cursor symbol is just flashing on the next line.

Comment: See my edit. Your while is the problem. It should stop when it is equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks! for mentioning the exact problem and don't misunderstand that I copied your answer because I am doing this from last 10 min!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you are looking for:-

```
import java.util.*;
public class sheet12t3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        hailstone(aNumber);
    }

    public static void hailstone(int x)
    {
        int count = 1;
        int max = 0;
        String results = "Hailstone series for the number " + x + " is ";
        while (x > 1)
        {
            if (x % 2 == 0)
                x = x / 2;
            else
                x = 3*x + 1;

           System.out.print(x+" ");
    max++;    
    }
    }
}
```